# How to Animation a light to glow brighter step by step in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to animate a glowing light. In animation ie when I press the light it glow step by step   light should glow slowly and finally glow brightly. I have less experience in android animation, can I implement this if so how please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at Android's animation system. specifically, you will probably want to design your effect to have two images, one, the unlit light. and then the light shining brightly.

Then you can use an [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html) to animate the bright shining light into view.

Comment: I have an ImageButton which has two states (selected, not selected) and it changes the drawable using selector.

If I use a AlphaAnimation, it starts from alpha=0, which makes the background visible and I dont want that. I need to have something like two images on top of each other and alpha animate just the top one.

How would I do that?